# Display pdf file within app

Tags: android, pdf-viewer

I have pdf file download in my device on known location. I want to display it within my application. I tried several pdf viewer libraries like:

> ```
> https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview         <--- This is deprecated.
> https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library <--- Does not display pdf properly. I mean it has several issues while loading pdf.
> https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer          <--- So far best I could find over the internet.
> ```

But **none of the above work on hyperlinks to navigate to certain header within the file**.

I know i can display pdf file in **Google drive viewer**, but I don't want that.
So anyone can suggest me relevant pdf viewer library in android which I can plug in my project?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." Perhaps you should file issues with the above library developers, with a PDF that can reproduce your problem. See also [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html).

Comment: you can open it inside webview in your application

Comment: @CommonsWare: I am asking to share me the way for hyperlinks within the file if you know. I am not asking to find me any tool or other things. I checked the list of issues for above libraries as well and my question is there in issues for https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer library. So, i was asking other way to achieve hyperlinks functionality if you know any.

Comment: @Hasmukhkachhatiya: I checked with that as well but it is not working with hyperlinks in the file. I want that functionality. I am not able to go to selected header in the file.

Comment: "I am not asking to find me any tool or other things" -- yes, you are. Your question has "So anyone can suggest me relevant pdf viewer library in android".

Comment: i think this may be help you for that hyperlink https://www.hrupin.com/2012/08/how-to-open-activity-by-android-webview-hyperlink-click-or-how-to-handle-hyperlink-click-in-android-webview

Comment: @Hasmukhkachhatiya. thanks for the link. But it is not helping me in case of pdf file.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I no where found any help. Please help to achieve the functionality of hyperlinks within the pdf file itself. Google Drive view is also not providing that.

Answer (score 0):

Use google doc viewer to view pdf without any external library.

```
String pdf = "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Comment: I checked with that as well but it is not working with hyperlinks in the file. I want that functionality. I am not able to go to selected header in the file.